# Navigating from one screen to another screen in Android using RubyMotion

Tags: navigation, screen, rubymotion

In the `MainActivity.rb` class, I have written this code to handle a button click:

```
 def onClick(view)
     puts "coming here"
    if view.getId == @button_id
      puts @text_box_value.getText.toString
    elsif view.getId == @register_id
      puts @text_box.getText.toString
  #intent will describes what operation to be performed
  i = Android::Content::Intent.new(getApplicationContext, RegisterActivity)
  startActivity(i)
    end
  end
```

I added the activity in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, yet it is showing this error:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class

I am struggling with this but i didn't find any link in RubyMotion.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but just as an aside, I'm hoping to solve these problems with ProMotion-Android soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your Rakefile

```
app.sub_activities = ['RegisterActivity']
```

Also instead of using `getApplicationContext` you could use `self`

Also try using `start_activity` instead.